# ListView sub-element background changes when list item clicked

Tags: android

I'm working on a Fragment that has a custom expandable ListView. When the ListView is selected, elements are added to two LinearLayouts within the selected list item and these layouts are made visible. Each of these new elements are selectable and have the following properties:

```
android:clickable="true"
android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
```

I noticed that the handling of this background selector state is different on my two devices. I've attached two sets of screenshots for these devices to compare the handling of the same code.

**Android 4.3.1 | CyanogenMod 10.2.1**
[Expanded](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Iog7D.png), [Sub-Element Clicked](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ralYY.png), [List Item Clicked](https://i.stack.imgur.com/80O7E.png)

**Android 4.0.4 | 2.6.38.8-aokp-bravo-ics**
[Expanded](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X4fYm.png), [Sub-Element Clicked](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mMZaV.png), [List Item Clicked](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7h1at.png)

As you can see on the 4.0.4 device when the whole list item is selected all the sub-elements get the focus highlight as well which is undesirable. How do I get around this?

Answer (score 0):

I got tired of dealing with the inconsistencies (or maybe I never properly learnt) and did the following, which may or may not be correct or suit your scenario (treat the code below more like pseudo code than Java).

```
class SomeAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    final int colorItemDefault;
    final int colorItemSelected;
    final int colorSubItemDefault;
    final int colorSubItemSelected;

    public SomeAdapter (final Context c) {
        final Resources res = c.getResources();
        colorItemDefault = res.getColor (R.color.item_default);
        colorItemSelected = res.getColor (R.color.item_selected);
        colorSubItemDefault = res.getColor (R.color.sub_item_default);
        colorSubItemSelected = res.getColor (R.color.sub_item_selected);
    }

    public View getView (final int position, final View convertView, final ViewGroup parent...) {
           final View view = makeNewViewOrRecycleExisting (...);
           final Item item = getItem (position);
           // bind content, etc...

           view.setBackgroundColor (isSelected (item) ? colorItemSelected : colorItemDefault);

          // similar logic for the sub items

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The color that you are seeing is because of the list view's listSelector property. The behavior of which effect will be rendered on list items depends upon the Android version and the theme that you have used for the application. To get around the problem either you set the listSelector to transparent or provide your own selector. You can set the listSelector in you xml or programmatically using either of them. Sets transparent color

```
android:listSelector="#00000000"

yourListView.setSelector(new ColorDrawable(0x0));
```